# Can `git diff --stat` be made to respect `diff.<driver>.textconv`?

Tags: git

I'm using a `textconv` filter. which works great when running `git diff` to see the actual differences, but any time I use `--stat` or `--numstat`, the numbers reflect the untransformed files (which lack newlines) rather than the converted files, so the output is not particularly useful (and can look kinda silly):

```
git diff --patch-with-stat
 foo | 2+-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/foo b/foo
index 061fe3c..192c371 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -1,2 +1,11 @@
 bar
 baz
+abc
+def
+ghi
+jkl
+mno
+pqr
+stu
+vwz
+yz
```

Clearly there's more than one line inserted in the patch...

Is there some way to tell `git` to use the converter for these cases as well?  Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem...

When we use git diff with **--stat** or **--numstat**, only the number of lines added and removed in the file is displayed. As the textconv filter converts the files and adds new lines, the line counts reported by **--stat** or **--numstat** do not correspond to the actual line counts in the converted file.

You can try to solve this problem by using the **--no-renames** option with git diff, which will disable rename detection. This ensures that the file paths in the patch output match the file paths in the working directory, so that the textconv filter is applied correctly.

For example, you can try running:

```
git diff --no-renames --patch-with-stat
```

With this, the correct number of lines added and removed will be displayed, based on the converted file.